# Custom Repository Base Class + QueryDslPredicateExecutor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I have found `QueryDslPredicateExecutor` very useful for reducing boilerplate, but it seems to be throwing a monkey wrench into the works. I'm now trying to extend `JpaRepository` with a custom base class repository, and on startup, Spring is having trouble instantiating repositories correctly.

```
//Custom base class
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface IdAwareRepository<A, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<A, ID> {
    // ID getId(A a);
}

// Base class implementation
public class IdAwareRepositoryImpl<A, ID extends Serializable>
    extends SimpleJpaRepository<A, ID> implements IdAwareRepository<A, ID>  {
    public IdAwareRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<A, ?> entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager);
    }
}

// Individual repo
@Repository
public interface MyPojoRepository extends JpaRepository<MyPojo, Integer>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<MyPojo> {
}

// Spring boot main application class
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = IdAwareRepositoryImpl.class)
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = {Application.class,   Jsr310JpaConverters.class})
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
      org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
      org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {}
```

I've tried several variations on this theme, but have not had luck in getting things wired up successfully. I came across a similar issue on Spring's issue tracker https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-674, but no explanation on the fix, just that code was being refactored to be easier to work with.

I'm getting the following error:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No
>   property findAll found for type MyPojo!   at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.(PropertyPath.java:77)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:329)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:309)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:272)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:243)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.(Part.java:76)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.(PartTree.java:235)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:373)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.(PartTree.java:353)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.(PartTree.java:84)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:62)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:100)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:211)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:74)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:416)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:206)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:251)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:237)
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)

Which to me says that Spring isn't able to wire up both the custom base class and `QueryDslPredicateExecutor` extensions to `JpaRepository`

Comment: I am hitting the exact same problem. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: No, not yet. I've been meaning to produce a small project that reproduces the error in order to give the Spring or Spring Data devs a reproduce-able error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar issue by having my base repository extend the QueryDslMongoRepository.
You may be able able to extend a similar class.

["No property exists found for type"... When using the QueryDslPredicateExecutor with MongoDB and Spring-Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37781375/no-property-exists-found-for-type-when-using-the-querydslpredicateexecutor/37800554#37800554)