# "No property exists found for type"... When using the QueryDslPredicateExecutor with MongoDB and Spring-Data

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, querydsl

I'm trying to use the QueryDslPredicateExecutor with MongoDB and Spring-Data, but it seems to be choking on the "exists()" property.

I'm using -

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:1.3.5.RELEASE  
com.querydsl:querydsl-mongodb:4.1.2  
com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.1.2  
org.mongodb.morphia:morphia:1.1.1
```

Stack Trace

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property exists found for type Tree!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:309) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:272) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:243) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:235) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:373) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:353) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:84) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.PartTreeMongoQuery.<init>(PartTreeMongoQuery.java:60) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory$MongoQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(MongoRepositoryFactory.java:168) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:435) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:220) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:266) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:252) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MongoRepositoryFactoryBean.java:108) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.9.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
```

The exception is being thrown from this class

```
package org.springframework.data.mapping
// PropertyPath.class 
....

/**
 * Creates a leaf {@link PropertyPath} (no nested ones with the given name and owning type.
 * 
 * @param name must not be {@literal null} or empty.
 * @param owningType must not be {@literal null}.
 * @param base the {@link PropertyPath} previously found.
 */
PropertyPath(String name, TypeInformation<?> owningType, List<PropertyPath> base) {

    Assert.hasText(name, "Name must not be null or empty!");
    Assert.notNull(owningType, "Owning type must not be null!");
    Assert.notNull(base, "Perviously found properties must not be null!");

    String propertyName = name.matches(ALL_UPPERCASE) ? name : StringUtils.uncapitalize(name);
    TypeInformation<?> propertyType = owningType.getProperty(propertyName);

    if (propertyType == null) {
        throw new PropertyReferenceException(propertyName, owningType, base);
    }

    this.owningType = owningType;
    this.isCollection = propertyType.isCollectionLike();
    this.type = propertyType.getActualType();
    this.name = propertyName;
}
```

The property (method) is coming from the QueryDslPredicateExecutor class that my Repository extends.

```
public abstract boolean org.springframework.data.querydsl.QueryDslPredicateExecutor.exists(com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate)
```

Here is the repository -

```
public interface TreeRepository extends ExtendedMongoRepository<Tree, String>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Tree>{}
```

Comment: It appears this is due to the Repository extending a base interface rather than the MongoRepository directly -
A similar question has been posted here - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36293960/custom-repository-base-class-querydslpredicateexecutor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up solving this by having my base repository extend and implement the QueryDslPredicateExecutor, rather than the higher level repository.

```
// Custom repository interface
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface ExtendedMongoRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends MongoRepository<T, ID>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<T>{

  public Page<T> query(Query query, Pageable pageable);

}


// Custom Repository Implementation
public abstract class ExtendedMongoRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends QueryDslMongoRepository<T, ID>
        implements ExtendedMongoRepository<T, ID> {

    private Class<T> clazz;
    private MongoOperations mongoOperations;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private MongoEntityInformation<T, ID> metadata;

    public ExtendedMongoRepositoryImpl(MongoEntityInformation<T, ID> metadata, MongoOperations mongoOperations) {
        super(metadata, mongoOperations);
        this.mongoOperations = mongoOperations;
        this.clazz = metadata.getJavaType();
        this.metadata = metadata;
    }

    @Override
    public Page<T> query(Query query, Pageable pageable) {
        List<T> list =  mongoOperations.find(query.with(pageable), clazz);
        return new PageImpl<T>(list, pageable, list.size());
    }
}  

// Entity Repository Interface
public interface TreeRepository extends ExtendedMongoRepository<Tree, String> {}
```

Comment: That public class is not abstract?

Comment: It is in my application, I just forgot to update my solution. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38153365/springboot-couchbase-integration maybe any idea for this?

Answer (score 1):

Changing

`extends SimpleJpaRepository`

for

`extends QueryDslJpaRepository`

in my base JPA repo impl made it for me.

Comment: Thanks.  Your answer helped me understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

@laffuste helped me to understand the issue.  If you are declaring the baseRepositoryClass (or extending it), it is not compatible with Querydsl.  You need to change it to the Querydsl base class, or extend it, which is compatible with both.

```
public class SimpleSpecRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends QuerydslJpaRepository<T, ID>;

@EnableJpaRepositories(value = "com.foo.repository", repositoryBaseClass = SimpleSpecRepository.class)
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class ServiceEntryPoint {}
```

Note:  It requires that all repository interfaces' entity mappings have Q mappings.  If you don't want this, you need to create a separate repositoryFactoryBeanClass:

```
public class SimpleSpecRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID>;

@EnableJpaRepositories(value = "com.foo.repository", repositoryFactoryBeanClass = SimpleRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
@SpringBootApplication
public class ServiceEntryPoint {}
```

---

```
 /**
 * Extension of the {@link JpaRepositoryFactoryBean} interface.
 *
 * @param <T>  the type of the repository
 * @param <S>  the type of the entity
 * @param <ID> the type of the entity identifier
 */
public class SimpleRepositoryFactoryBean<T extends JpaRepository<S, ID>, S, ID extends Serializable>
        extends JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<T, S, ID> {

    /**
     * Creates a new {@link SimpleRepositoryFactoryBean} for the given repository
     * interface.
     *
     * @param repositoryInterface must not be {@literal null}.
     */
    public SimpleRepositoryFactoryBean(Class<? extends T> repositoryInterface) {
        super(repositoryInterface);
    }

    @Override
    protected RepositoryFactorySupport createRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
        return new SimpleJpaRepositoryFactory<S, ID>(entityManager);
    }

    /**
     * Extends the JPA specific generic repository factory.
     * 
     * @param <S>  the type of the entity
     * @param <ID> the type of the entity identifier
     */
    private static class SimpleJpaRepositoryFactory<S, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepositoryFactory {

        /**
         * Creates a new {@link SimpleJpaRepositoryFactory}.
         * 
         * @param entityManager must not be {@literal null}
         */
        public SimpleJpaRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
            super(entityManager);
        }

        @Override
        protected Class<?> getRepositoryBaseClass(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {

            if (isQueryDslExecutor(metadata.getRepositoryInterface())) {
                return QuerydslJpaRepository.class;
            } else {
                return SimpleSpecRepository.class;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Returns whether the given repository interface requires a QueryDsl specific
         * implementation to be chosen.
         * 
         * @param repositoryInterface
         * @return
         */
        private boolean isQueryDslExecutor(Class<?> repositoryInterface) {

            return QUERY_DSL_PRESENT && QuerydslPredicateExecutor.class.isAssignableFrom(repositoryInterface);
        }

    }

}
```

Note:  This is only for complex configurations.  If you have a simple configuration, you should just be able to do the following:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.foo.repository")
```

The default configuration should support Querydsl or SimpleJPA automatically.