# Spring Data with QueryDslPredicateExecutor no property findAll found for type error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I tried to follow the tutorial in [Spring Data JPA with QueryDSL](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/)

My version of the code is the following:
 spring-boot = 1.3.8.release
 query-dsl = 3.7.4

My entity is the following

```
@Entity
@Table(name = BatchAPIEntity.TABLE)
public class BatchAPIEntity extends BatchEntity {

    @JsonView(View.API.class)
    @Column(name = KEY_NIT)
    String nit;
}
```

My Repository is the following

```
public interface BatchApiRepository extends JpaRepository<BatchAPIEntity,Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<BatchAPIEntity>{}
```

When I compile and build the code the follow error is show

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findAll found for type BatchAPIEntity!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:77)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:329)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:309)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:272)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:243)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:235)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:373)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:353)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:84)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:62)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:100)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:211)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:74)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:416)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:206)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:251)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:237)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1641)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    ... 47 common frames omitted
```

My error is similiar to the given in the following question, but the problem is that it isn't answer

[Error in findAll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36293960/custom-repository-base-class-querydslpredicateexecutor)

I tried also this answer but without any good result

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37800554/5192019

Comment: This is my exact problem too.

Comment: I add an answer to this question, try the approach and please tell me if this solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that I could solve this problem, after some read is to use QueryDslJpaRepository instead of two separate interfaces as follows:

```
public interface BatchApiRepository extends QueryDslJpaRepository<BatchAPIEntity, Long>
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this approach on monday.

Comment: Ahh, you know how it works... Monday... sure :) I just worked around, sadly. There are things which are more important this, actually. But I am preparing for round 2 and will happen in the near future. I will dig it up.